# Automatic substitution of fractions

Tags: symbolic, replacement

I have several equations with many variables, and here and there I would like to do a variable substitution. For example, in the equation:

```
a (b + 42 c / d)
```

I might want to remap variables *a * b --> p* and *a * c / d --> q* in order to get:

```
p + 42 q
```

Can *Mathematica* do this? I tried to play with the `With[]` and `Rule[]` function and the like, but that doesn't seem to produce anything. I can imagine that *Mathematica* is not capable of doing such a thing, but I thought it would be worth asking.

**And the pro question:**
And then very much related to this: is there a way to use `With[]` not to set a single variable but to set variable relations, e.g. the sum or product of two variables. So that this:

```
With[{a * b = 5},  a (b + 42 c / d)] (* This doesn't work*)
```

would reduce to:

```
5 + 42 a * c / d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rules = {a b -> p, a c / d -> q}
Expand[a (b + 42 c/d)] /. rules
(*p + 42  q*)
```